# Calling only once or caching the data from a $http get in an AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke, angular-services

I have a simple app in DNN. Below is my code.
What am I trying to do is create a service which call the GET api once. So when the same data from input were called twice the service will call the same api. I'm using network in inspect element to find the calling functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';

    var myApp<%=ModuleId%> = {};
    var isDlgOpen;

    try {
        myApp<%=ModuleId%> = angular.module('myApp<%=ModuleId%>', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
    }
    catch (e) {
        myApp<%=ModuleId%> = angular.module('myApp<%=ModuleId%>', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
    }

    //Service
    myApp<%=ModuleId%>.service('myService', ['$http', '$q', function ($q, $http) {
        this.data;
        var self = this;
        this.submit = function () {
        if (angular.isDefined(self.data)) {
            return $q.when(self.data)
        }
        return $http.get($scope.apiGetUrl).then(function (response) {
            self.data = response;
        })
    }
}]);

//Controller
myApp<%=ModuleId%>.controller('myCtrlr<%=ModuleId%>', function (myService, $scope, $http, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.submit = function (ev) {
    $scope.portalAlias = 'http://<%=PortalSettings.PortalAlias.HTTPAlias %>';
    $scope.apiGetUrl = $scope.portalAlias + '/desktopmodules/ORSIModule/api/RepairStatus/getRepair?JobNo=' + $scope.jobNo + '&SerialNo=' + $scope.serialNo;
    //form is valid

    if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
        $scope.isLoading = true;
        return $http.get($scope.apiGetUrl).then(
            function (response) {
                if (response.data) {
                    $scope.myForm.$setSubmitted();
                    $mdDialog.show(
                        $mdDialog.alert()
                        .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('dnnModule<%=ModuleId%>')))
                        .clickOutsideToClose(true)
                        .title('title: ' + response.data.status)
                        .textContent('Thank you.')
                        .ariaLabel('Status Alert Dialog')
                        .ok('Close')
                        .targetEvent(ev)
                        .hasBackdrop(false)
                    );
                } else {
                    alert("Not found.");
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

// Bootstrap the module
var appDiv = document.getElementById("dnnModule<%=ModuleId%>");
angular.bootstrap(appDiv, ["myApp<%=ModuleId%>"]);
```

Please somebody help me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the cache property to true in the get request:

```
$http.get(url, { cache: true}).success(...);
```

Also you can use:

```
$http({ cache: true, url: url, method: 'GET'}).success(...);
```

Another approach is to use cachefactory service:

```
var cache = $cacheFactory('myCache');

var data = cache.get(someKey);

if (!data) {
   $http.get(url).success(function(result) {
      data = result;
      cache.put(someKey, data);
   });
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to set this globally on startup if you want by setting `$httpProvider.defaults.cache = true` in a module config function.